# if i type "Ctrl+Z",it will crash,how to fix it?

Tags: c++, inputstream, eof

```
    vector<string> svec;
    string str;
    while (cin >> str&&!cin.eof())
    {
        svec.push_back(str);
    }
    for (auto c:svec)
    {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
```

If I input `tt tt tt`,the output is `tt tt tt`.
But if i input nothing ,i type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> ( windows + vs2013)will crash.
So i try to fix it.

```
 while (!cin.eof())
    {
        cin >> str;
        svec.push_back(str);
    }
```

Now , if i input nothing , I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will not crash.
But if i input `tt tt tt`,the output is `tt tt tt tt`.

Now I don't know how to fix it. Please help me .

Comment: did you use a debugger to see where it crashes? also using a stringstream instead of `std::cin` might be a good idea, in which you fill stringstream with EOF. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: `&&!cin.eof()` is redundant. `operator>>` will return the stream object, which evaluates to `false` when it reaches EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try just:

```
while (cin >> str)
{
    svec.push_back(str);
}
```

**Why extra tt**
If I unroll your while loop, it goes as:

```
1. buf [tt tt tt, not eof], vec []
  a. is eof no
  b. read and push str
2. buf [tt tt, not eof], vec [tt]
  a. is eof no
  b. read and push str
3. buf [tt, not eof], vec [tt tt]
  a. is eof no
  b. read and push str
4. buf [, not eof], vec [tt tt tt]
  a. is eof no
  b. read and push str [read fails, str contains old value and eof is set]
5. buf [eof], vec [tt tt tt tt]
  a. is eof yes
  b. break
```

You can also read [Why while(!feof(...) ) is almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: I tried your code in vs2013, it still crashed if i input nothing and then typed `ctrl + z`,so can you give me other advice ?

Comment: You can try `do { if(cin >> str) svec.push_back(str);} while (!cin.eof())`. Although I think extra check is redundant and you should try to locate the source of crash.

Comment: I tried ,it's also crashed . If I  use `!cin.eof()`in `while`(not in `do{}while`),it will not crashed .But as your [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)say,**it enters the loop one more time than the author expects. If there is a read error, the loop never terminates.**.If I don't use `cin.eof()`,it will crash.

Comment: I checked the location of crash and fixed it . Thank you very much!